# Thymeleaf. How to compare if the date is from future, or past?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I want to check if the date which is in Employee.dateOfTermination is after date "now". Unfortunetely, after running following code, I get nothing on data:

```
<td> <div th:switch="${employee.dateOfTermination}"> 
                            <span th:case="'&lt; now'">CASE 1</span>
                            <span th:case="'&gt; now'" th:text="${#dates.format(employee.dateOfTermination, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}">CASE 2</span></div></td>
```

Here comes the problem, the syntax of thymeleaf does seem unappliable and disgusting for me. I tried with th:if, and parsing a int.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it like this:

```
<span th:if="${employee.dateOfTermination.before(#dates.createNow())}">Case 1</span>
<span th:if="${employee.dateOfTermination.after(#dates.createNow())}">Case 2</span>
```

Or maybe, if you do like the switch:

```
<div th:switch="${employee.dateOfTermination.before(#dates.createNow())}">
    <span th:case="true">Case 1</span>
    <span th:case="false">Case 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: When I compare two dates with `.before` in thymeleaf, I get a parsing error. I also can't find any documentation about `.before` or `.after`? How do I enable those?

Comment: @Nixen85 -- `.before` and `.after` are present on the [`java.util.Date` object](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)).

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to insert a new parameter in the backend and pass it through to Thymeleaf.
For example you insert the parameter "age" in backend and its getter returns a corresponding string based on comparison with the time now (e.g. "OLDER" or "YOUNGER"). Then you add it to the ModelView of the respective Thymeleaf page, where you can use a th:switch:

> `<th:block th:switch="${age}">`
>   `<th:block th:case="OLDER">`
>     `<span th:text="Age is older than now" style="..."></span>`
>   `</th:block>`
>   `<th:block th:case="YOUNGER">`
>    `<span th:text="Age is younger than now" style="..."></span>`
>   `</th:block>`
> `</th:block>`