# How do I validate between two dates using LocalTime using Springboot and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, localdate

I have a class with this field in:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate passDate;
```

I created two LocalDate variables which I want to check between (for example)

`LocalDate a = LocalDate.of(1995, 1, 01);
LocalDate b = LocalDate.of(2140, 12, 31);`

I was using @PastOrPresent but that does not stop users from entering a date like year 3050.

I started making a method in the domain class, where the passDate field resides, however I really do not know where the validation goes and how to call this validation method. (Here is a snippet of what I was trying to do but unsure where to put it? (maybe its wrong too!))

```
if (!(passDate.isBefore(a) && passDate.isAfter(b))) {
return passDate; }
```

Wasn't sure where this goes? What method? How do I call this validation? or is there another way. I have looked online for so long and can't figure out what to do.
I have a thymeleaf form with this field (which was using the PastOrPresent validation to return an error message on submit)

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pass_date">Enter the pass date</label>
                <input type="date" th:field="*{passDate}" name="pass_date" id="pass_date"
                       class="form-control"/>
                <p class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('passDate')}" th:errors="*{passDate}"></p>
            </div>
```

Here is the post controller

```
@PostMapping("/admin/examform")
public String createExamForm(@ModelAttribute("examform") @Valid Examform examform,
                                    BindingResult bindingResult,
                                    @AuthenticationPrincipal final User user, Model model){
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println(bindingResult.getAllErrors());
        model.addAttribute("examform", examform);
        return "examformhtml";
    }else{
        examformservice.createExamForm(examform);
        model.addAttribute("loggedInUsername", user.getUsername());
        return "examformsuccess";
    }

}
```

Where examformservice is a class variable of my service which links to my repository which is

```
@Override
public void createExamForm(Examform examform) {
    String sql = "UPDATE examform SET passDate=? WHERE studentId=?";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, examform.getPassDate(), examform.getStudentId());

}
```

Where would I put the validation? and what would the input be?

Comment: Sorry to add this little bit of anger against `Java`, but `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, `java.util.Calendar` (even if its not truely a date... it is sometimes used as a date...), `LocalDateTime`... We have bunch of ways to manage dates, but they aren't converting themselves easily from one kind to another.

Comment: Should I use java.util.Date instead? @Marc

Comment: No. LocalDate and LocalDateTime are the future of the dates. History will bury in twenty years these old java.util.Date and java.sql.Date.... I hope !

Comment: You can always add your own validation annotations  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Comment: Or, if you're looking for a fast solution, leave it up to Thymeleaf and provide `a` and `b` as dates.  It's generally better to keep more complex logic on the server-side though.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49946115/thymeleaf-how-to-compare-if-the-date-is-from-future-or-past

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a JSR annotation you can work your way from this one:

```java
@Constraint(validatedBy=AfterValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface After {
    String message() default "must be after {value}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    String value();
}
```

And its validator:

```
public class AfterValidator implements ConstraintValidator<After, LocalDate> {

    private LocalDate date;

    public void initialize(After annotation) {
        date = LocalDate.parse(annotation.value());
    }

    public boolean isValid(LocalDate value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean valid = true;
        if (value != null) {
            if (!value.isAfter(date)) {
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

The above is exclusive (the exact date will be invalid), you may want to tweak it.

To use it is only to add annotation in model bean:

```
@After("1995-01-01")
private LocalDate passDate;
```

The inverse (`@Before`) I leave you as an exercise :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this before you assign it to the field. So in your form submit you do something like that:

```
LocalDate input = ...;
if (!(input.isBefore(a) && input.isAfter(b))) {
    // set the field
} else {
    // handle error here
    // throw exception or just print something
}
```

Comment: Do you mean add that to my post controller method? or in my domain class where the passDate variable is? I want the else clause to display an error like the one with     @PastOrPresent(message="Please select a past or present date") which I can use in the html form if they try to submit it, it would say that error, but I am unsure how to do that.

Comment: Yes you add this to your post controller method.

Comment: For the error handling I would say you cann add an url parameter and based on that you display an error message in the html (hide it initially and display it when the parameter is set) or you can go with exceptions, that depends on your project setup

Comment: I added an edit to show my post method and my repository query. I am a bit unsure where to place the validation and how to link it with the actual passDate field before submit.